# Prolog loop until true is returned

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to generate a 4x4 magic square puzzle, and once a solution that is valid is found the list gets printed. I have the rules to print a given solution and generate a random board as well as solve it, but I don't know how I could have the generate fact be called until it returns true, and then print it. Here is my code:

```
check([[A,B,C,D],[E,F,G,H],[I,J,K,L],[M,N,O,P]]) :-
   A+B+C+D=:=34,
   E+F+G+H=:=34,
   I+J+K+L=:=34,
   M+N+O+P=:=34,
   A+E+I+M=:=34,
   B+F+J+N=:=34,
   C+G+K+O=:=34,
   D+H+L+P=:=34,
   A+F+K+P=:=34,
   D+G+J+M=:=34.

solve([[A,B,C,D],[E,F,G,H],[I,J,K,L],[M,N,O,P]]) :-
   permutation(
          [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16],
          [A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P]),
   check([[A,B,C,D],[E,F,G,H],[I,J,K,L],[M,N,O,P]]).

generate :-
   random_permutation(
          [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16],
          [A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P]),
   solve([[A,B,C,D],[E,F,G,H],[I,J,K,L],[M,N,O,P]]),
   printlist([[A,B,C,D],[E,F,G,H],[I,J,K,L],[M,N,O,P]]).

printlist([X|List]) :-
    write(X),nl,
    printlist(List).
```

I know there isn't looping in the traditional sense with Prolog, but I don't quite understand how I could run until a valid case is found(also I am aware the brute force method used here could take quite some time).

Any insight as to solving this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: "I don't quite understand how I could run until a valid case is found" Just call the predicate and this is exactly what Prolog will do. But it seems that your approach is very inefficient which is why it seems to not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program is calling for another approach!

Just look at the goal:

```
permutation(
          [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16],
          [A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P]),
```

This goals will produce 16! solutions. In other words: 20 922 789 888 000. So, in case you have a fast computer at your disposal, ...

To improve this situation, we have to reduce the number of solutions or answers. But, how? Prolog has something very nice: **the logic variable**. That is, we can subsume many solutions within a **single answer** using **constraints**.  In this case `library(clpfd)` will help:

```
?- Xs = [A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P], Xs ins 1..16, all_different(Xs).
Xs = [A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I|...],
A in 1..16,
all_different([A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H|...]),
B in 1..16,
C in 1..16,
D in 1..16,
E in 1..16,
F in 1..16,
G in 1..16,
H in 1..16,
I in 1..16,
J in 1..16,
K in 1..16,
L in 1..16,
M in 1..16,
N in 1..16,
O in 1..16,
P in 1..16.
```

**One answer** now subsumes all twentytrillion solutions!  With further constraints we can now write:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

magquad_([[A,B,C,D],[E,F,G,H],[I,J,K,L],[M,N,O,P]], Zs) :-
   Xs = [A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P],
   Xs ins 1..16,
   all_different(Xs),
   Zs = [A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P],
   A+B+C+D#=34,
   E+F+G+H#=34,
   I+J+K+L#=34,
   M+N+O+P#=34,
   A+E+I+M#=34,
   B+F+J+N#=34,
   C+G+K+O#=34,
   D+H+L+P#=34,
   A+F+K+P#=34,
   D+G+J+M#=34.

magquad(Xss) :-
   magquad_(Xss, Zs),  % use of core-relation or model
   labeling([], Zs).   % separate labeling
```

### Let the printing be done by the toplevel!

```
?- time(magquad(Xss)).
% 106,412 inferences, 0.052 CPU in 0.053 seconds (99% CPU, 2049006 Lips)
Xss = [[1, 2, 15, 16], [12, 14, 3, 5], [13, 7, 10, 4], [8, 11, 6, 9]] ;
% 36,910 inferences, 0.027 CPU in 0.027 seconds (99% CPU, 1384976 Lips)
Xss = [[1, 2, 15, 16], [13, 14, 3, 4], [12, 7, 10, 5], [8, 11, 6, 9]] ;
% 209,488 inferences, 0.089 CPU in 0.089 seconds (100% CPU, 2348606 Lips)
Xss = [[1, 2, 16, 15], [13, 14, 4, 3], [12, 7, 9, 6], [8, 11, 5, 10]] ...
```

As you can see, Prolog can now ridiculously fast find all those magic squares!